# No return value on using OpenXML command in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, openxml

This is my XML parameter that I set to `@XMLSave` parameter and send to a stored procedure

```
<ROOT>
   <P>
      <ID>123456789</ID>
      <Name>admin</Name>
    </P>
    <Group>
       <GroupCardID>14</GroupCardID>
    </Group>
</ROOT>
```

and I try to get `ID` value with this command

```
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @idoc OUTPUT, @XMLSave
```

but when I select values return no value

```
select * 
from OPENXML (@idoc,'/Root/P',2)  With(ID int)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @XmlParameter XML = '<ROOT>
   <P>
      <ID>123456789</ID>
      <Name>admin</Name>
    </P>
    <Group>
       <GroupCardID>14</GroupCardID>
    </Group>
</ROOT>'

SELECT
    @XmlParameter.value('(/ROOT/P/ID)[1]', 'int')
```

I always prefer the native XQuery support over the clunky old `OPENXML` stuff.....

Comment: thank you . but this is on old system that i have to fix some problem and cannot change its structure at this time

Answer (score 0):

I Found the answer finally: 
OpenXML parameter is case sensitive : 
my XML value start with "ROOT" and openxml parameter was "Root"

Comment: yes i do. but i am working on project that was developed before me. and have to fix through OPENXML.